# Use RN Expo Web Browser dismissBrowser when on specific URL

Tags: react-native, expo

Trying to achieve the following scenario

1. Client clicks a button and it opens the Expo web browser with a URL e.g `wwww.example.com/test`
2. User does something and is redirected to a URL like `wwww.example.com/success`
3. The app recognizes the URL and auto-closes the web browser

It correctly opens the web browser but nothing happens afterward when I go to `wwww.example.com/success`.

I'm not getting any errors and with the iOS Expo preview, I get no `console.log` triggers, but with the Web Expo preview, I get generic logging.

Code below

```js
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
    import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
    
    
    export const WebVerification = () => {
      const [redirectData, setRedirectData] = useState(null);
    
      const _handleRedirect = (event) => {
        console.log('handle Request is called')
        let data = Linking.parse(event.url);
        console.log(data)
        if( data.url === "wwww.example.com/success") {
          WebBrowser.dismissBrowser();
        }
    
        setRedirectData(data);
      };
    
      const _openBrowserAsync = async () => {
        try {
          _addLinkingListener();
          let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(
            `wwww.example.com/test`
          );
    
        } catch (error) {
          alert(error);
          console.log(error);
        }
      };
    
      const _addLinkingListener = () => {
        Linking.addEventListener("url", _handleRedirect);
      };
    
      const _removeLinkingListener = () => {
        Linking.removeEventListener("url", _handleRedirect);
      };
    
      const _maybeRenderRedirectData = () => {
        console.log("check RenderRedirect" + redirectData)
        if (!redirectData) {
          return;
        }
    
        return (
          <Text style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
            {JSON.stringify(redirectData)}
          </Text>
        );
      };
    
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Redirect Example</Text>
          <Button onPress={_openBrowserAsync} title="Open Browser" />
          {_maybeRenderRedirectData()}
        </View>
      );
    };
```